# How to sort by object property with a minus sign in mongoose?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to sort in mongoose by using the minus sign with the property and it seems to work fine (both ways) if I do directly on the property.
So something like this works for me:

```
.sort({ name: -1 })
```

and this also works

```
.sort({ '-name': -1 })
```

But when I try to sort on the basis of a sub-property, it works only one way,

```
{ 'payment.cash.budget': -1 }
```

Above query works fine.
But the following doesn't work:

```
{ '-payment.cash.budget': -1 }
```

Any reason why mongoose is behaving that way? 
I can't use (easily) use '1' instead of '-1' because the query comes from the front end.

- Mongoose: 4.13.0
- MongoDB: 3.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using the minus sign with a property name for Mongoose sorting, you just pass the string itself, not an object:

```
.sort('payment.cash.budget')  // Ascending

.sort('-payment.cash.budget') // Descending
```